# How do i modify my create function in Django model manager

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

So i have  this model:

```
class Token(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    code = models.IntegerField(default=code)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=True)
```

as you can see I have an `expiration_date` field. The reason why I set it to `(null=False, blank=True)` is because I want it to fill itself based of the `date_created` field, and I'm trying to do that from the model manager create method

I have little to no experience in model manager outside of custom user model manager.
Here's my first failed attempt:

```
class TokenManager(models.Manager):

    def create(self, user, code, date_created):

        exp = date_created + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)

        token = self.model(user=user, code=code, date_created=date_created, expiration_date=exp)

        token.save()

        return token
```

basically my goal here is to get the value of `date_created` field, add the value by 10 minutes and set it as the `expiration_date`. can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use a ModelManger here. You can just set the `expiration_date` based on the field `date_created` by overwriting the `save` method.

Edit:
It is not possible to use self.date_created datetime within the save method. However it is possible to use `django.utils.timezone.now()`which is also used by `auto_now_add` .

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Token(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    code = models.IntegerField(default=code)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=True)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Set the expiration_date based on the value of auto_now_add
        self.expiration_date  = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
        super(Token, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I got an error that says `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.timedelta'`

Comment: I didn't know that an auto_now_add field cannot be accessed in the save() method. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: May I ask why did the super method in our custom save function need the `Token` model and `self` as the parameters?

Comment: You can read more about the `super` method and it's usage in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27134600/15353043).